# No alert is displayed for onbeforeunload event when use url() function of Nightwatch framework

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, onbeforeunload

I'm following an example from nighwatch page:
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/master/examples/tests/onbeforeunload.js
with custom command for `onbeforeunload` event.

```
module.exports = {
  disabled: true,

  'go to page with unload handler': function(client) {
    client
      .url('https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000);
  },

  'navigate away from page WITH unload handler': function(client) {
    var hasDialog = false;

    client
      .hasOnBeforeUnload(function(result) {
        this.verify.equal(result, true, 'The page should have an onbeforeunload handler');
        hasDialog = result;
      })
      .url('http://google.com', function() {
        if (hasDialog) {
          this.acceptAlert();
        }
      })
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000);

  },
///....
/// other parts

}
```

Expect: has alert for changing url

Actual: Nothing. This test is passed!. Even if no alert is displayed when i tried to switch to new url http://google.com from current url https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm

Logs:

```
i Connected to localhost on port 4444 (3241ms).
  Using: firefox (74.0.1) on windows 10.0 platform.

Running:  go to page with unload handler

√ Element  was visible after 24 milliseconds.

OK. 1 assertions passed. (661ms)
Running:  navigate away from page WITH unload handler

√ Passed [equal]: The page should have an onbeforeunload handler
 Error while running .acceptAlert() protocol action: An attempt was made to operate on a modal dialog when one was not open.

√ Element  was visible after 14 milliseconds.

.....
```

P/s: its OK if i do above steps manually instead of nightwatch test

Test is still passed after removing `this.acceptAlert();` function

Do you know root causes of this issue? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding some wait after the initial url load? It may be that you are trying to navigate even before the js code is loaded and so you don't see it during automation.

Comment: Where should I do it? url() doesn't have method to add a timeout value. When we navigate to new url, alert should be displayed for current page

Comment: client
      .url('http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .pause(10000);

Comment: I tried to add pause() function but still have the same error. Beside, the pause() is not choice to  wait any thing in my case.